# CakePHP routing same action, different route for different params

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-routing

I want to connect the following routes:

register/about_you

my_profile/edit/about_you

...to the same action.  But I want the second route to bring in a parameter that I can use to identify that we are on the edit page, not registration.

I currently have in my routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/register/:action/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'registration'
    )
);

Router::connect('/my_profile/edit/:action/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'registration',
        'edit' => 1
    )
);
```

This works to connect the URLs above to the correct place - and I can use `$this->params['edit']` in the controller.  However, when I try to build a link, using

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'registration', 'action' => 'about_you', 'edit' => 1, $i));
```

I get

/register/about_you/0/edit:1

Instead of

/my_profile/edit/about_you

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try interchanging it like this?

```
Router::connect('/my_profile/edit/:action/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'registration',
        'edit' => 1
    )
);
Router::connect('/register/:action/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'registration'
    )
);
```

If it is like this, you'll get /my_profile/edit/about_you/0

Comment: You're right, that's all that I needed to do!  Thanks